# how to add a sensor tag in IBM bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot

I am trying to connect TI SensorTag to the IBM Internet of Things. I connected BeagleBone to linux and and I logged in into BeagleBone in following way.
ssh root@192.168.7.2

But I am not sure how to get the mac address ? Can someone please help me in this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Diwesh you need to get the device id while registering the sensor tag ...

please follow these steps to connect your sensor tag:

ssh root@192.168.7.2

ifconfig eth0

your will see something like this :

Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 09:00:12:90:e3:e5  .......

HWaddr will be your mac address.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your device’s media access control (MAC) address,which needs to be entered json file while registering sensor tag.

Below is the reference link which may help you on developing app:

http://thoughtsoncloud.com/2014/10/internet-things-iot-ibm-bluemix-growth-innovation/

https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2014/07/16/bluemix-internet-things/